# How to handle this type of Web API 2 routing scenario?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2, url-routing, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-web-api-routing

How can I define a set of routes (or modify my controllers) that would allow me to handle these 2 types of URI requests?  Please note that I can modify my classes and the routes, but I can't change the structure of the URIs.

Example 1 URI *routes correctly* to `WidgetsController`

**api/widgets/{widget id}**

Example 2 URI *routes incorrectly* to `WidgetsController`.  I want it to route to `WidgetActionController`.

**api/widgets/{widget id}/widgetaction/{widget action id}**

Here are my controllers

```
Public Class WidgetsController

    Inherits ApiController

    ' GET api/widgets/{widget id}
    Public Function [Get](id as integer) As Widget
        Return DataAccess.GetWidgetByID(id)
    End Function

End Class

Public Class WidgetActionController

    Inherits ApiController

    ' GET api/widgets/{widget id}/widgetaction/{action}
    Public Function [Get](id as integer, action as integer) As Boolean
        'Get Widget By ID
        'Perform {action} on Widget    
    End Function

End Class
```

Here are my routes:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("Data",
                 "api/{controller}/{id}/{year}/{month}/{day}",
                 New With {Key .id = RouteParameter.[Optional],
                 .year = RouteParameter.[Optional],
                 .month = RouteParameter.[Optional],
                 .day = RouteParameter.[Optional]})

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("WidgetAction",
                           "api/widgets/{id}/widgetaction/{action}", 
                           New With {Key .controller = "WidgetAction"})
```

Answer (score 1):

Routing is order specific. The only thing you need to do in this scenario is to put the more specific route before the generic route.

```
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("WidgetAction",
                       "api/widgets/{id}/widgetaction/{action}", 
                       New With {Key .controller = "WidgetAction"})

 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("Data",
             "api/{controller}/{id}/{year}/{month}/{day}",
             New With {Key .id = RouteParameter.[Optional],
             .year = RouteParameter.[Optional],
             .month = RouteParameter.[Optional],
             .day = RouteParameter.[Optional]})
```

The problem is that your `Data` route always matches in every case that the `WidgetAction` route could potentially match. The first match always wins, making your second route an unreachable execution path. If you reverse the order, the first route will not match if the URL doesn't contain `widgets` as the second segment and `widgetaction` as the fourth segment, allowing the `Data` route to be checked.